# SQL most common value not accurate

Tags: sql

**EDITED:**

I have this script to find most common value in the column. 
How to remove empty result row from the results?

```
SELECT top (5) WorkCompletedBy, COUNT(WorkCompletedBy) AS ActionCount
FROM  ServiceTicketReport
GROUP BY WorkCompletedBy
ORDER BY ActionCount DESC
```

https://snag.gy/A0Vyom.jpg
Where could be the issue? thanks.

Comment: there are 5813 `null`s in workcompletedby column. use `where workcompletedby is not null` to exclude nulls from the result.

Comment: Im still getting 9259 results

Comment: What happen if you remove the `TOP(5)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query shows you that 5813 actions were completed by worker without any symbol in his name (or only spaces). And if you remove "top(5)" you will see other workers with their action count.

Comment: Now i got what u mean! but i dont understand why the script with where WorkCompletedBy is not null still shows me total rows

Answer (score 1):

You are limiting the results by using the top (5)

Comment: Yes, because I want to get top 5 results. But it should not impact total count.

Comment: @Fresher any rows where  the workby person is not in the top 5 will be totally excluded.

Comment: @Martin Smith I changed it to top (9999) and im getting the same results, just that it shows everybody who is in the records (226 persons) https://snag.gy/SK20cG.jpg

Comment: @Fresher And if you add up all the counts what number do you get?

Comment: @Martin Smith as Volodymyr Duduladenko explained, first number 5813 its the total rows but the total done by 'blank' records. so now its clear, i guess the script works fine. just was confused. thanks

Comment: @Martin Smith how could I remove that first line from the list (5813). WHERE WorkCompletedBy IS NOT NULL doesnt work ?

Comment: `WHERE WorkCompletedBy <> ''`